# Table including explicit NAs in R > 3.4.0

Tags: r, na, tidyverse

EDIT: The accepted answer has helped the scales fall from my eyes; this change is an improvement and not annoying after all.

In the help file for `table`, it is now written:

> Non-factor arguments a are coerced via factor(a, exclude=exclude).
>   Since R 3.4.0, care is taken not to count the excluded values (where
>   they were included in the NA count, previously).

This is *annoying*.  Before, you could call `table(x, exclude = NULL)` and get explicit confirmation of the number of `NA` values. Now, if there are none, you aren't told. Observe:

```
vec_with_no_nas <- c("A", "B", "B", "C")
vec_with_nas <- c("A", "B", NA, "C")

table(vec_with_no_nas)
table(vec_with_no_nas, exclude = NULL)

table(vec_with_nas)
table(vec_with_nas, exclude = NULL)
```

This gives output:

```
> table(vec_with_no_nas)
vec_with_no_nas
A B C 
1 2 1 
> table(vec_with_no_nas, exclude = NULL)
vec_with_no_nas
A B C 
1 2 1
```

See? no explicit confirmation of zero NAs.

What I really want is something like the old behavior, which was:

```
> table(vec_with_no_nas, exclude = NULL)
vec_with_no_nas
A B C <NA>
1 2 1 0
```

FWIW, if the vector *does* have NA values, `table(x, exclude = NULL)` will tell you:

```
> table(vec_with_nas)
vec_with_nas
A B C 
1 1 1 

> table(vec_with_nas, exclude = NULL)
vec_with_nas
   A    B    C <NA> 
   1    1    1    1
```

I work in base and in the `tidyverse`.  Is there a drop-in `table` replacement that will do explicit confirmation of no NAs?

Comment: Maybe you could use the `useNA` argument? `table(vec_with_no_nas, useNA="always")`. I currently don't have access to 3.4.0 to test directly.

Comment: That does it!  if you put table(vec_with_nas, useNA = "always")
table(vec_with_no_nas, useNA = "always") in an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try setting the useNA argument to "always". In R 3.2.5,

```
table(vec_with_no_nas, useNA="always")
```

adds an NA column, even though no NAs are present.

```
vec_with_no_nas
   A    B    C <NA> 
   1    2    1    0
```

The online help file for 3.4.0 (and 3.2.5) says

> useNA controls if the table includes counts of NA values.

So this argument seems to do directly address what you want to do. The exclude argument allows the user to directly drop levels of a factor variable from the table output.

```
table(vec_with_no_nas, exclude="A")
vec_with_no_nas
B C 
2 1
```

Which can be cleaner than dropping unwanted levels from a constructed table object.

*note:*
The online 3.4.0 help file mentions a pathological case in the simultaneous use of both exclude and useNA arguments and also provides an example that might be worth further exploration.

Comment: I noticed that in R 4.1.3 `useNA` defaults to `"no"`, which I think is suboptimal because NAs will get dropped implicitly. `useNA="ifany"` is my favorite and should be default imho.

Comment: P.S.: Using `summary()` instead of `table()` automatically invokes `table(useNA="ifany")` for factors as input

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` can be used to quickly create summary tables and includes `NA`s by default.

```
# Create Dataset
library(data.table)
df=data.table(V1=c('A','B','B',NA),V2=1:4)
df
#      V1 V2
# 1:    A  1
# 2:    B  2
# 3:    B  3
# 4: <NA>  4

# Count Table
df[,.N,by=V1]
#      V1 N
# 1:    A 1
# 2:    B 2
# 3: <NA> 1

# Proportion Table
df[,.N/nrow(df),by=V1]
#      V1   V1
# 1:    A 0.25
# 2:    B 0.50
# 3: <NA> 0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use `sum(is.na(dataset$columnname))`

```
table(is.na(dataset$variablecolumn))
table(is.na(dataset$columnname))
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question. You are filtering out `NA` values while th question asks to include the alongside other values.